# Reason to use startproc, killproc and checkproc in Sys-V type init scripts in OpenSUSE

Tags: opensuse, sysvinit

In OpenSUSE 11.4 `sysvinit-tools` package contains `startproc`, `killproc` and `checkproc` binaries which according to `/etc/init.d/skeleton` file and OpenSUSE documentation should be used in Sys-V type of init scripts. What is the idea of those binaries? Couldn't one achieve the same functionality of `startproc`, `killproc` and `checkproc` with `nice`, `sudo`, `sleep` and other similar tools?

Answer (score 0):

Let's first define the specific programs:
[startproc](http://www.linux-tutorial.info/modules.php?name=ManPage&sec=8&manpage=startproc)

> startproc: startproc  and  the LSB variant start_daemon check for all processes of the specified executable and starts it if no processes are found. startproc does not use the pid to search for a process but the full path of the corresponding program which is used to identify the executable

[killproc](http://www.linux-tutorial.info/modules.php?name=ManPage&sec=8&manpage=killproc)

> killproc sends signals to all processes that use the spec­ified executable. If no signal name is specified, the signal SIGTERM is sent. killproc does not use the pid to send a signal to a pro­cess but the full path of the corresponding program  which is used to identify the executable

[checkproc](http://www.linux-tutorial.info/modules.php?name=ManPage&sec=8&manpage=checkproc)

> checkproc checks for running processes that use the speci­fied executable. checkproc does not use the pid to verify a process but the full path of the corresponding program which is used to identify  the executable.

nice, sudo, sleep do nothing related to the above programs.

Off course you could do the same logic from kill/start/checkproc in any scripting language (bash for ex.) or other compiled language. But the purpose of those programs is to offer this functionality to all users that need it, so they don't have to bother to write/rewrite the same logic on different distributions and different OSs.